# How to use Android Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

i have a question concerning Android. I'm new to Android and trying to make a tiny App with tabs as main navigation element. Well i'm not 100% sure how to work with tabs correcty. Maybe you can guide me there.

As far as i know there are basically 2 different options. I can either use tabs in the action bar or with TabHost. The former is in my opinion the right way to go. What are the pros and cons here?

If i use the tabs in the action bar it is recommended to have not more than 3 tabs. What if i need more navigation options (as i understood it's not like iOS tabs where you have a "..." option)?

Should i use a different type of navigation element? (i guess in my case i'll have 4 "tabs")

Thanks in advance!

Comment: TabHost IMO has a lower learning curve but I agree the action bar is the right way to go. Just start a new project from samples and create the API demo. Take a look at the code there and how it's implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Action bar is definitely the way to go. TabHost is deprecated and Google prefers that you go with Action bar since it really fits in with their design philosophy after ICS.

You can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to support all android versions after 2.1 (Eclair).

Here are some tutorials to get you started:

http://avilyne.com/?p=180

http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/using-an-actionbar-in-your-application-with-actionbarsherlock/

Video tutorials:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avcp6eD_X2k

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mOMOh-fH-c

Comment: You should copy the XML and code from one of those tutorials and reference it with a link, in case the link should die in the future.

Comment: Agreed. But @patman seems to be new to Android. I think a full tutorial is needed for understanding the concepts. A snippet of xml wouldn't provide too much value here IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But before starting with another library i'd like to understand and use the native Android classes (i know the API is staying the same). But the tutorials only show how to install that Library and set up a demo app.

Comment: You can refer the official docs for a great tutorial on Action Bar  
(developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).  

There is a tabs section in there as well. Conceptually both of them are pretty much the same so if you learn the official one, ActionBarSherlock shouldn't be too hard to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
Activity sampleActivity = (Activity) View.getContext();
ActionBar actionBar = sampleActivity.getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
tab.setText("This is the name of the tab");
actionBar.addTab(tab, true);
```

Comment: where would i do it? so far i have only 1 activity that is my first tab. Later on i'll have 4 activities for all the tabs. Do i have to put this code in every activity?

Comment: You would have to add this code to any activity that would have a view to display tabs. you would loop thru' the tabs setting the selected value depending on whether it is allowed to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

USe this Example for solve his/her problem

This main xml file for Tab

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget`enter code here`
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

java File

```
     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    Resources ressources = getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

            Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this,FirstClass.class);

    TabSpec tab1 = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Android")
            .setIndicator("",ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_android_config))
            .setContent(intentAndroid);

Intent intentAndroid2 = new Intent().setClass(this,FirstClass.class);

    TabSpec tab2 = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Android")
            .setIndicator("",ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon))
            .setContent(intentAndroid2);


            tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);

           tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

}

Comment: This is a code sample that's everywhere around the internet. But it doesn't answer a single question of mine. Furthermore i'd rather not use TabHost.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 5;
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Items";
                case 1:
                    return "Food";
                case 2:
                    return "Drink";
                case 3:
                    return "soft";
                case 4:
                    return "warm";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: change the number 3 with the number of your tabs

Comment: (i) Fix your indentation (ii) Is this question still relevant 3 years later ?

Comment: because i've been locked on it,i serached here and when i found the solution i have share it